# How to prove that ( the left hand side equals the right hand side in the following problem? )

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am trying to prove this problem:

How can I prove this
\begin{align*}
   \frac{2j+1}{z^{n+1}}  \sum_{n=0}^{2j} [\frac{(2j)!}{(2j- n)! n!}]^{\frac{1}{2}}f^*_n \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(t)^n}{(1+t)^{2j+2}}dt
 \end{align*}  is equal to $=$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{2j} [\frac{((2j-n)!n!)}{(2j!)}]^{\frac{1}{2}}f^*_n z^{-n-1}
  \end{align*}
where (j=1/2,1,3/2,2....),(n is an integer  ≥  0 ) and f^*_n   is a complex conjogate of
f^_n(complex state)

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Once you recognize the integral is an alternative representation for the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), the result follows almost immediately.

Comment: f^*_n is a complex conjugate of f^_n (the coefficients of  z^{-n-1}). For example when j=1 the right hand side become \begin{align*}
 f_b(z)=(0.5000 - 0.0000i) z^{-1} + ( 0.2500 - 0.4330i) z^{-2} +(-0.2500 -0.4330i)z^{-3}
  \end{align*}\\

Comment: ?  on the LHS, $z^{n+1}$ is outside the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{2j}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be
\begin{align*}
   & (2j+1)\sum_{n=0}^{2j}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}   [\frac{(2j)!}{(2j- n)! n!}]^{\frac{1}{2}}f^*_n \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(t)^n}{(1+t)^{2j+2}}dt
\\&\qquad=
\sum_{n=0}^{2j} [\frac{((2j-n)!n!)}{(2j)!}]^{\frac{1}{2}}f^*_n z^{-n-1}
\end{align*}
Notice in the first one, I put the factor inside.  In the second one, I replaced $(2j!)$ with $(2j)!$.

The only non-trivial step in doing this is:
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{t^n}{(1+t)^{2j+2}}\,dt = \frac{(2j-n)!n!}{(2j+1)!}
$$